# PHP - remove overlapping entries in array

Tags: php, arrays

I've got and array that contains opening hours.  Each entry is a time frame the shop can be open.

`day` is the day with 0 being Sunday,  1 Monday, 2 Tuesday...  upto 6 Saturday

`stime` is the start opening time and `etime` is the closing time

Looking at the example below I have 3 entries for Wednesday (3)

```
Wed 09 : 00 - 12 : 00
Wed 09 : 00 - 17 : 00
Wed 13 : 00 - 17 : 00
```

Obviously if the shop is open 0900 - 1700, then the other 2 entries are not needed as they fall within this time frame.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => 1
            [stime] => 09 : 00
            [etime] => 17 : 00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2
            [stime] => 09 : 00
            [etime] => 17 : 00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [day] => 3
            [stime] => 09 : 00
            [etime] => 12 : 00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [day] => 3
            [stime] => 09 : 00
            [etime] => 17 : 00
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [day] => 3
            [stime] => 13 : 00
            [etime] => 17 : 00
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [day] => 4
            [stime] => 09 : 00
            [etime] => 17 : 00
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [day] => 5
            [stime] => 09 : 00
            [etime] => 17 : 00
        )

)
```

Is there any way to filter the array so it doesn't show time frames that are already covered ?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean there are multiple [stime] and [etime] keys for each day ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? This looks like an excellent exercise for test-driven-development

Comment: @maniksidana for the example above there are 3 Wed entries. Entry '2' covers the time periods entries 1 & 3 cover, so there is no need for 1 & 3.  Thanks

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks for the reply, I'm not sure what to try with this. So far I've go the data into an array, sorted that array by Day and Start Time, but now I need a pointer on how I can filter and remove overlapping entries. Thanks

Comment: What do you expect to happen if there are 2 time periods for the same day that do not overlap? Or can this not happen?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Currently `Monday is 0900-1700` if there is another entry for `Monday 0730-1300' then I would expect both entries to be shown.  Unless there is a way to merge them so it displayed Monday 0730-1700 ?

Comment: @Tom What if there was 2 entries for monday, one of them `0730-1300` and `1400-1700`? Unless that isn't possible.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Unfortunately that is possible !  In that case I'd like both to be shown as they are unique time frames.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_reduce` for this, here is the example:

```
$result = array_reduce($arr, function($_arr, $item) {
$day = $item['day'];

if (!key_exists($day, $_arr)) {
    $_arr[$day] = $item;
} else {
    if (floatval(str_replace(':', '.', $_arr[$day]['stime'])) > floatval(str_replace(':', '.', $item['stime']))) {
        $_arr[$day]['stime'] = $item['stime'];
    }
    if (floatval(str_replace(':', '.', $_arr[$day]['etime'])) < floatval(str_replace(':', '.', $item['etime']))) {
        $_arr[$day]['etime'] = $item['etime'];
    }
}

return $_arr;
}, []);

sort($result);

print_r($result);
```

Here is the result:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [day] => 1
        [stime] => 09:00
        [etime] => 17:00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [day] => 2
        [stime] => 09:00
        [etime] => 17:00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [day] => 3
        [stime] => 09:00
        [etime] => 17:00
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [day] => 4
        [stime] => 09:00
        [etime] => 17:00
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [day] => 5
        [stime] => 09:00
        [etime] => 17:00
    )
```

)

Comment: Thanks this helps, but there is an issue.  If Wednesday had the following entries `Wed 09 : 00 - 12 : 30` & `Wed 13 : 30 - 17 : 00`  Then it shows `Wed 09 : 00 - 17 : 00` and misses the time the shop is closed between 12:30 & 13:30.

Comment: I'm glad to here that! You will need to adjust the logic in the "else" part. :)

Comment: thanks can you explain how this works. I've not used array_reduce before.